# Is there a way to make eclipse IDE run faster when you have a limited RAM like 8GB?

Tags: eclipse

Why eclipse freezes sometimes or seem to require more RAM power than it's allocated? Well if you have ran into performance issues with the IDE, I know it can be very frustrating sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

The original "eclipse.ini" file that comes right after you install the IDE, has some flows that might interrupt the execution of code, from my experience it happened a lot while developing spring boot apps, eclipse would just froze and I would have to restart my laptop, now I finally got through.

So I started digging and was clear that the problem is in the original "eclipse.ini" details.

For making life easier of people who might need eclipse since it's free, I pasted the current details I am using in my installation, (the bold information is not in the original file), remove the (** **), and use the appropriate details, not only eclipse runs faster it also runs better all the maven generated projects.

I tried different cofiguration details on the "eclipse.ini" file until it worked. So I got it as below. The lines bolded (do not consider the ** **), are the ones I added. You might refer to the website where I got the basic information I used to achieve theis

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/wp-content/qa/uploads/2021/04/eclipse_ini.png

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\Carlos\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.700.v20221108-1024
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Users/Carlos/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007/jre/bin
-**vmargs**
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-**Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home.eclipse-workspace**
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-**XX:+UseG1GC**
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms256m
-**Xmx2048m**
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```